# Linked List (Loop)

Tags: java, loops, linked-list

I'm having a trouble doing a loop for Linked List. 
I wanted to try to input ID and Name from the user, but it seems that the last inputted details are being overwrite throughout the whole linking thing. But when I use the instantiation `(myLinkedList.insertFirstLink("name", id))`, and it does work.

Here's my code..

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

    class Example
    {
        public static int ID;
        public static int ans;
        public static String name;
        public Example next;

        public Example(int ID, String name)
        {
            this.ID = ID;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void display()
        {
            System.out.println("ID: "+ID + " - " + name);
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return name;
        } 

        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
        {   
            BufferedReader inpt = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));

            int x = 0;
            LinkList myLinkedList = new LinkList();

            while(x<=2)
            {
            System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
            name = inpt.readLine();

            System.out.print("Input ID#: ");
            ID = Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine());

            System.out.println();

            myLinkedList.insertFirstLink(name, ID);
            x++;
            }

         /* myLinkedList.insertFirstLink("Vishera", 2341);
            myLinkedList.insertFirstLink("Bulldozer", 1234);
            myLinkedList.insertFirstLink("Allendale", 3214);
            myLinkedList.insertFirstLink("Wolfdale", 4312); */

            myLinkedList.displayLink();

        }
    }

    class LinkList
    {
        public Example head;
        public Example tail;

        public LinkList()
        {
            head = null;
            tail = head;
        }

        public boolean isEmpty()
        {
            return(head == null);
        }

        public void insertFirstLink(String name, int ID)
        {
            Example newLink = new Example(ID, name);
            if(head==null)
            {
                head = newLink;
                tail = head;
            }
            else 
            {
                tail.next = newLink;
                tail = newLink;
            }
        }

        public void displayLink()
        {
            Example theLink = head;

            while(theLink != null)
            {
                theLink.display();

                System.out.println("The Next Link: " + theLink.next);

                theLink = theLink.next;

                System.out.println();

            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Debug your code and you'll find the problem in less than 3 seconds.

Comment: Why did you make your fields static in your Example class? Make them instances one and it should work as expected.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Each `Example` object has a `next` field.

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Comment: @ZouZou - I made it static because since I'm asking the user to input something, isn't it something to be done in order to avoid the non-static variable?

Comment: @JaySuzumiya I think you're confusing what does static mean. You should read this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: @ZouZou - Thanks, will do.
Sorry, I'm still a beginner and trying to learn.

Comment: @JaySuzumiya No problems :) We are all beginners!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in your `Example class`

First of all you have not created instance variable and have created class variable using static. for `creating instance variable` use only `private` keyword.

**`Corrected Code`**

```
public class Example {
private int ID;
private int ans;
private String name;
public Example next;

public Example(int ID, String name) {
    this.ID = ID;
    this.name = name;
}

public void display() {
    System.out.println("ID: " + ID + " - " + name);
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    int userId;
    String userName;
    BufferedReader inpt = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            System.in));

    int x = 0;
    LinkList myLinkedList = new LinkList();

    while (x <= 2) {
        System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
        userName = inpt.readLine();

        System.out.print("Input ID#: ");
        userId = Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine());

        System.out.println();

        myLinkedList.insertFirstLink(userName, userId);
        x++;
    }

    /*
     * myLinkedList.insertFirstLink("Vishera", 2341);
     * myLinkedList.insertFirstLink("Bulldozer", 1234);
     * myLinkedList.insertFirstLink("Allendale", 3214);
     * myLinkedList.insertFirstLink("Wolfdale", 4312);
     */

    myLinkedList.displayLink();

}

public String toString() {
    return name;
}

}

class LinkList {
public Example head;
public Example tail;

public LinkList() {
    head = null;
    tail = head;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (head == null);
}

public void insertFirstLink(String name, int ID) {
    Example newLink = new Example(ID, name);
    if (head == null) {
        head = newLink;
        tail = newLink;
    } else {
        tail.next = newLink;
        tail = newLink;
    }
}

public void displayLink() {
    Example theLink = head;

    while (theLink != null) {
        theLink.display();

        System.out.println("The Next Link: " + theLink.next);

        theLink = theLink.next;

        System.out.println();

    }
}
}
```

After making above changes,

## OUTPUT

```
Enter Name: a
Input ID#: 1

Enter Name: b
Input ID#: 2

Enter Name: c
Input ID#: 3

ID: 1 - a
The Next Link: b

ID: 2 - b
The Next Link: c

ID: 3 - c
The Next Link: null
```

Comment: I tried your code, but for some reason I got an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's what I need to continue for my work.

Again, thanks. Saved me.